# Error al datos en mysql con python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Estoy intentando meter los datos, con variables ya que lo usare para meter una base de datos mas extensa pero no puedo encontrar cómo.

````
try: 
    conexion  = mysql.connector.connect (user = 'root', password= 'poderamericano123',
                                    host = 'localhost',
                                    port = '3306',
                                    database = 'escuela',
                                    charset='utf8'
                                    )
    
    # Get a cursor
    clave = 32
    periodo = 2025-2026
    entidad = "zacatecas" 
    
    
    
    cursor = conexion.cursor()

    # Execute a query
    comando = ('INSERT INTO estado (Clave_entidad, Periodo, Entidad ) VALUES (['clave'] ,"200-2022","zacatecas")')
    cursor.execute(comando)
    # Fetch one result
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    #print("Current date is: {0}".format(row[0]))
    for x in row:
        print(x.id)
    conexion.commit()
  
    # Close connection
    #cursor.close()
    print("Conexion correcta")
except :
    print ("Error en la Conexion")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La estructura para crear una conexión es la siguiente:

```
self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            password ='poderamericano123',   
            port = 3306,
            db='escuela'
        )
```

El resultado de error que tienes puede ser porque en el parámetro de puerto, se debe ingresar un valor `int` y estas ingresando un valor `str`.
Entonces prueba quitando las comillas simples del parámetro de puerto.

En caso de no poder solucionarlo con lo comentado anteriormente, entonces usa la librería `import pymysql` que tiene un mejor uso para una conexión, y se aplica la misma lógica explicada anteriormente.

**Veo que han actualizado la pregunta**

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
comando = """INSERT INTO estado (Clave_entidad, Periodo, Entidad ) VALUES (%s ,'%s','%s');"""
insert_blob_tuple = (clave, periodo, entidad)
cursor.execute(comando, insert_blob_tuple)
row = cursor.fetchall()
```